How to make a nested list NOT inherit it's parents styling
I have some lists on my page that are nested, and I'm having an issue with styling them the way I want. When each list item is hovered, I want the background of the item to be a colour and for the text the change from black to white, or blue to white depending on if it's a link or not. I can get this to work fine, but what I DON'T want is for the parent to a submenu to highlight ALL the links inside of it when the parent is hovered over. For instance, say I have a list-item called 'home' that opens a sublist inside of it. I would only want 'home' the change it's text and background-color on hover, but what's happening is every single link in the submenu is changed when 'home' is hovered over. I know why this happens, but I want to know how to stop it. I've tried it with closing the initial lists tag, but that's not the right way to do it and it screws up the styling of the lists anyways. Is there anyway I can achieve what I want? I have noticed this seems to only happen if the start of the nested link is a link. Below is a snippet of the lists I'm trying to work with. (I've changed the link hover to grey so you can hopefully see what I'm talking about.)


.filesubmenu {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 164px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #bdbebd;
  border-top: 1px #dedfde solid;
  border-right: 1px #000 solid;
  border-bottom: 1px #000 solid;
  border-left: 1px #dedfde solid;
  outline: 1px #fff outset;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}

.filestab ul li {
  display: block;
  padding-right: 16px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  width: calc(100% - 1px);
  height: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-size: 12px;
}

.filestab ul li:hover {
  background-color: #00007b;
  color: #fff;
}

.filestab ul li a {
  color: #0000ff;
}

.filestab ul li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}
.filepop1,
.filepop2 {
display: block;
position: absolute;
outline: white 1px outset;
outline-offset: -2px;
border-right: 1px #000 solid;
border-top: 1px #dedfde solid;
border-left: 1px #dedfde solid;
border-bottom: 1px #000 solid;
background-color: #bdbebd;
width: 164px;
left: calc(100% - 3px);
top: -1px;
}
<div class="filestab">
  <ul class="filesubmenu">
    <li><span>I'm an example submenu!</span></li>
    <li><span>Example</span></li>
    <li><span><a href="">Example with link</a></span></li>
    <li><span>Example</span>
      <ul class="filepop1">
        <li><span><a href="">Example with link</a></span></li>
        <li><span><a href="#">Example with link</a></span></li>
        <li><span>Example</span>
          <ul class="filepop2">
            <li><span><a href="">Example with link</a></span></li>
            <li><span><a href="#">Example with link</a></span></li>
            <li><span>Example</span></li>
            <li><span>Example</span></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span>Example</span></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span>Example</span></li>
    <li><span>Example</span></li>
    <li><span>Example</span></li>
    <li><span>Example</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- FILESTAB -->



I have tried almost every way to style lists and links that I can possibly think of, and NOTHING has worked :(

I think it would be just as simple as splitting out the colour rule to just target  > span (e.g. any span elements in the li that are a direct descendant), e.g.
.filestab ul li:hover > span, .filestab ul li:hover > span a {
  color: #fff;
}



.filesubmenu {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 164px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #bdbebd;
  border-top: 1px #dedfde solid;
  border-right: 1px #000 solid;
  border-bottom: 1px #000 solid;
  border-left: 1px #dedfde solid;
  outline: 1px #fff outset;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}

.filestab ul li {
  display: block;
  padding-right: 16px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  width: calc(100% - 1px);
  height: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-size: 12px;
}

.filestab ul li:hover {
  background-color: #00007b;
}

.filestab ul li:hover > span, .filestab ul li:hover > span a {
  color: #fff;
}

.filestab ul li a {
  color: #0000ff;
}

.filepop1,
.filepop2 {
display: block;
position: absolute;
outline: white 1px outset;
outline-offset: -2px;
border-right: 1px #000 solid;
border-top: 1px #dedfde solid;
border-left: 1px #dedfde solid;
border-bottom: 1px #000 solid;
background-color: #bdbebd;
width: 164px;
left: calc(100% - 3px);
top: -1px;
}
<div class="filestab">
  <ul class="filesubmenu">
    <li><span>I'm an example submenu!</span></li>
    <li><span>Example</span></li>
    <li><span><a href="">Example with link</a></span></li>
    <li><span>Example</span>
      <ul class="filepop1">
        <li><span><a href="">Example with link</a></span></li>
        <li><span><a href="#">Example with link</a></span></li>
        <li><span>Example</span>
          <ul class="filepop2">
            <li><span><a href="">Example with link</a></span></li>
            <li><span><a href="#">Example with link</a></span></li>
            <li><span>Example</span></li>
            <li><span>Example</span></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span>Example</span></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span>Example</span></li>
    <li><span>Example</span></li>
    <li><span>Example</span></li>
    <li><span>Example</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- FILESTAB -->




Ahhh, this fixed it exactly!!! Thank you SO much!!! :D
